# Captcha solution which can be used with App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, api, captcha

Is there a simple captcha solution which can be easily integrated with a form deployed using Google App Engine? I am using Python.

Comment: Python. Updated the questions also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recaptcha. It does work with Python.

http://www.google.com/recaptcha

http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/otherplatforms.html

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/recaptcha-client

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test, but I guess this can work: http://daily.profeth.de/2008/04/using-recaptcha-with-google-app-engine.html, he use reCaptcha